# symmetric difference. Why$ A\triangle U = A'?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that if $A' = U \backslash A$, then $A\triangle U = A'$. I have already tried by the formal definition of $A\triangle B (A\triangle B = (A\cup B)-(A\cap B))$. However, I still don't get a valid answer. Do you guys have a clue? If so, I would like to share some ideas with you. Thanks in advance!

Well. I started by the definition of the complement of a set, i.e. if $A ⊆ U \rightarrow A′= U\backslash A$. Then, I tried to use this theorem in order to get to the proof $A\triangle U =  (A\cup U)-(A\cap U) \rightarrow A\triangle U = (A-U)\cup(U-A)$. Therefore, I wrote that $A\triangle U = (A-U)\cup A'$. The problem is, now I don't know how to continue nor if it's correct.

Comment: Please edit to include you efforts.  Can you show either inclusion?  That is, can you show that $A'\subseteq A\,\Delta\,U$ or that $A\,\Delta\,U\subseteq A'$?

Comment: You should *include* the details of your attempt you mention *in your question*. Thius will lessenthe odds your question will be closed, as well as increase the odds someone here can give you hints.

Comment: Hint: What is $U$ ?

Comment: The shortest explanation is because $0+1=1$ is odd.

Comment: $A \triangle U = (A \cup U) - (A \cap U)$. Now, $A$ is a piece of $U$, right? So, what are $A \cup U$ and $A \cap U$?

Comment: @azif00
Well, A∪U = U and A∩U = A. Ohhhh, I see it now xD. Then, you have U\A which is A'

Comment: THX so much to all you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think the path forward will become more clear if you restate the set difference between two sets, say $A-B$, as $A \cap B'$. See below...

$A \triangle U$

$= (A \cup U) - (A \cap U) \:\:\: $ by definition of symmetric difference of sets

$= (A \cup U) - A \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: $ by identity law

$= U - A \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ by domination law

$= U \cap A' \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ by definition of difference of sets

$= A' \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ by identity law